# Comments Box + Interuser Chat + Chat Support - altogether in the same site. How?

Tags: user-expectation, chat, customer-support, live

Here I go again with a major doubt.
My IT team is building a marketplace website, and I've decided to add these 3 features:

1) a **Comments/Discussion Forum** on certain Resources/blog pages. I think about using one of these: Disqus, Isso, Remarkbox, Muut, HTMLCommentbox, or similar, where users would log using social credentials rather than the site's.

2) a **Interuser chat window** - users (buyers/sellers) will be able to chat each other after they meet certain criteria, triggering their chat window.

3) a **Live Chat Support** window. Currently I have implemented Tawk.to in our website on some pages only.

Now the tricky issue: I don't know how to implement all these 3 features successfully without damaging the UX. I am afraid a multitude of options might cause confusion for the user, because I want each feature to be unobtrusive as possible.

My questions are:

- should the Live Chat Support only be available to unlogged users, or only when logged in users navigate to specific pages? Because if logged-in users have Interuser chat windows active, and suddenly while moving to a different page, the Chat Support could pop-up overlapping everything. That is the kind of erratic behaviour that I want to avoid.
- would the Comments section on the specific areas cause some concern/awkwardness to logged in users? Once again I want to build the commented page visually simple as possible.
- what are your views on these matters? Anyone had to implement these 3 features altogether and dealt with these "dilemmas"?

I really would appreciate any tips. Cheers, folks!

Comment: What is the procedure for a user to start an interuser chat?  What kind of requirements, UI, are there groups/lists etc?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all of these:

1. comments on posts (like any regular blog post)
2. a feature where users could chat between them
3. a common live support chat

In this scenario, option 2 is the only one that is uncommon and might represent an issue. However, I think the answer is very easy. Simply make the **inter-user chat window** embedded in its own page and problem solved.

**Think about this:**

**Comments** belong to their own page, so there's nothing you can do about that .

**Live Chat** is needed for all users, including registered users and visitors. After all, it may be more important for visitors (so you can convert them to registered users) than for known users.

So, the only option is to work on the **inter-user chat**. If you add it as a popup, it will *clash* with the **support chat**, just like you say. So you know this is NOT a good solution, therefore you have 2 options:

1. **displaying the support chat only on certain pages:** this would go against the spirit of live support chat. Just imagine an user looking for help, so she needs to go to main page just to be able to see the live chat! (not to mention the confusion if users see 2 different chat windows depending on the page they are!)
2. **forget about popping-out the inter-user chat**: clearly the best option, it's not confusing, it won't collide with the live support chat, and it will require **intentionality**: users will get here because they **WANT** to, not by accident.

## In short:

Like I said before, simply **embed the intra-user chat window in its own page** and problem solved

**Edit:** there's a chat here, although very few people knows about it since it's not very visible, but you can see what I mean at [UX.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Devin, thanks for the pointers. I have been reflecting over this. I think I will scrap the Live Chat support, and leave the intra-user chat as it is embedded in each page. I guess it makes more sense to sacrifice the chat support at this stage. What do you think?

Comment: I meant embedded in its own page, not all pages. Just like UX.SE chat, which has its own page. Taking off the live chat will depend on your needs. If you think you don't need it, then go ahead. But if think your users will appreciate it, then make sure to test